# How to work with AllowPaging in property?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

i have a gridview and i am giving allowpaging true in the gridview..now i saw pagenumber in the bottom of gridview..now when i click the page number the click is not working ..it is showing some error like "The GridView 'GridView1' fired event PageIndexChanging which wasn't handled."..how to get away with it??

my code

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" BackColor="LightGoldenrodYellow" BorderColor="Tan" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="2" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="None" PageSize="1" Width="544px" >
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="PaleGoldenrod" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="cdd">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
        <FooterStyle BackColor="Tan" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="Tan" Font-Bold="True" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="PaleGoldenrod" ForeColor="DarkSlateBlue" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="DarkSlateBlue" ForeColor="GhostWhite" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FAFAE7" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#DAC09E" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E1DB9C" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#C2A47B" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

my codebehind

```
public partial class usersshow : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    ArrayList myArrayList = ConvertDataSetToArrayList();

        // Display each item of ArrayList
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("User Id");
        dt.Columns.Add("Problem Name");
        dt.Columns.Add("Status");

       foreach (Object row in myArrayList)
        {
            dt.Rows.Add();
            dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["User Id"] = ((DataRow)row)["userid"].ToString();
            dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["Problem Name"] = ((DataRow)row)["problemname"].ToString();
            dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["Status"] = ((DataRow)row)["status"].ToString();

        }

       GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();

 }

 public ArrayList ConvertDataSetToArrayList()
 {

    string con = " ";
    con = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString();
    SqlConnection objsqlconn = new SqlConnection(con);
    objsqlconn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT userid,problemname,status FROM problemtable", objsqlconn);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    SqlDataAdapter myAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    myAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd;

    DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
    myAdapter.Fill(myDataSet);

    ArrayList myArrayList = new ArrayList();
    foreach (DataRow dtRow in myDataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        myArrayList.Add(dtRow);
    }
    objsqlconn.Close();
    return myArrayList;
 }
```

Comment: what kind of data source are you binding the grid to?

Comment: i have edited my post..i think you will get idea...Thomas Taylor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add onpageindexchanging event in page and check you have missing of that.

So aspx code is

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" BackColor="LightGoldenrodYellow" 
 BorderColor="Tan" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="2" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="None" PageSize="1" 
 Width="544px" AllowPaging="true" onpageindexchanging = "GridView1_PageIndexChanging"  >
```

Code Side

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
            GridView1.DataSource = GetDataTable();
            GridView1.DataBind();
           }

 }
 public System.Data.DataTable GetDataTable()
 {
    ArrayList myArrayList = ConvertDataSetToArrayList();

    // Display each item of ArrayList
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("User Id");
    dt.Columns.Add("Problem Name");
    dt.Columns.Add("Status");

   foreach (Object row in myArrayList)
    {
        dt.Rows.Add();
        dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["User Id"] = ((DataRow)row)["userid"].ToString();
        dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["Problem Name"] = ((DataRow)row)["problemname"].ToString();
        dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["Status"] = ((DataRow)row)["status"].ToString();

    }

    Return dt;
    }


  protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
   {
    GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    GridView1.DataSource = GetDataTable();
    GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: i don't have datasource..look you can see that i am just retrieving data in an arraylist and just display it in gridview..in that case what will i give in Gridview1.Datasourc=" ";??

Comment: check my updated answer so you will get the solution